# Translating Kendo-UI grid with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, translation, ngx-translate

I've got a problem with translating Kendo-UI grid component by ngx-translate.

There's part of my code. I created a grid component which just contains basic showcase of our grid component.

Then I added into assets/i18n/en.json our translations. And I wrote a service which extends MessageService from Kendo-UI: code

```
export class CustomMessageService extends MessageService {

  constructor(@Injectable() private translateService: TranslateService) {
    super();
  }

  get(key: string): string {
    return (this.translateService.instant(key) as any).value;
  }
}
```

and inside app.module I used this service instead of their service (same as in docs)

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MessageService,
      useClass: CustomMessageService
    }],
```

And there's a problem. Just get method inside CustomMessageService doesn't see my translates.

Stackblitz: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7aeks

I don't know why I cannot translate it properly. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLTR: load locales before use instant

**translateService.instant** is sync but you need to be sure that your translations already loaded.

I've fix your example here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcipfd

It's based on this comment
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/517#issuecomment-299637956